# Infinite time of rotation

Tags: andengine

I want the rotation of the sprite. So that I used RotationModifier, but in that I have to specify the time interval you want the rotation. But I want to create rotation which was infinite. So please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LoopEntityModifier](http://andengine-doc.googlecode.com/hg/org/anddev/andengine/entity/modifier/LoopEntityModifier.html) is the way to go!

Not sure, but it may end as something like this:

```
LoopEntityModifier EntityModifier =
                   new LoopEntityModifier( new RotationModifier(yourargs) );
```

Answer (score 5):

What about (pseudo-code):

```
update(float dt){
    sprite.rotation += degreesPerSecond * dt;
}
```